# Regression for prediction versus understanding independent associations

Tags: regression, prediction, association-measure

I see that regression is used for 2 main purposes:

1. To develop a predictive model for future use
2. To understand associations. Specifically, to know which of the predictors have an "independent association" with the outcome or response variable. This is used especially in biomedical field.

How should approach and application of regression be different in above 2 purposes? Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my limited experience (2nd year undergrad) that the main difference in approach depending on purpose is in the variable selection.

If you're trying to make a predictive model only for the purpose of prediction, it makes sense to include any predictors which correlate significantly with the response (within some reason, it takes a long time to gather data). However, when you're looking for the association of a specific predictor with the response, you want to be pretty careful not to include too many things which correlate with that predictor. This can lead to issues with multicollinearity (when two or more predictors correlate with the response exactly in the same way as another)

For example, let's say the relationship I care about is between how much an indoor plant grows and how much it was watered. I might reasonably make a model like: growth ~ water + sun. It would still make sense to include the variable about how much sun the plant got, as that information is probably not highly related to how much water it got. There would be examples in the data of plants that got a lot of water and sun, a lot of water but no sun, a lot of sun but no water, and not much sun or water. So I (or a regression package) could see how much growth increased due to the water, and how much due to the sun.

However, it would not make sense to include a variable measuring the overall skill of the plant's keeper, since that variable is probably highly correlated with how much water the plant got. In a model with water and grower_skill, each relationship would be obscured somewhat by the other. It would be hard to tell how much taller the plant got due to the water, and how much it got taller due to the grower's skill, since all good growers water their plants and all bad growers don't. There would be no examples in the data of plants with high grower skill and low water or vice versa.

So, if I was making a predictive model, my predictions would probably be slightly better if I included grower_skill (maybe at the high levels they use fertilizer or something). However, if I included it, the association of water and growth would be less clear.

If you're unfamiliar, here's a site with some more on multicollinearity:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.minitab.com/blog/understanding-statistics/handling-multicollinearity-in-regression-analysis%3fhs_amp=true

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. If we have a regression of `growth ~ water + sun + skill`, the `skill` will show significant relation if it has relation with `growth` through factors other than `water`.  This will be valid even there is multicollinearity. That is how most biomedical studies analyze results of multiple regression analyses. Isn't it correct?

Comment: So, I think if growth was really different from water it could be significant, but in that case water could also be significant. Multicollinearity is usually resolved by R with only one p value getting tanked but the relationships could be totally wrong. For example if X1 = X2, and Y1 = X1, that means Y1 could also equal 3X1 - 2X2, there's no good way to tell. If you're worried you might have multicollinearity it's worth trying to run a VIF multicollinearity condition number (more on VIF in turbo kit above) calculation. (I don't know any biomedicine but I think that's right.)

Comment: Regarging regression `growth ~ water + skill`. If all benefit of skill is through water, then only water will be significant. If skill is promoting growth through water as well as through other mechanisms, both water and skill will be significant. Do you agree?

Comment: See here: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32631300/  It states: "In the multiple logistic regression model analysis after adjusting for confounding variables, obesity, physical activity and HDL-C  were the significant and independent determinants of uncontrolled hypertension in the cohort". Note "independent determinants". This is how multiple regression is most commonly analyzed in biomedical studies.

Comment: I agree that both could be significant of skill promotes growth through other mechanisms. However if the only way skill promotes growth is through water, we don't know which of the two will be significant for sure (it's determined by an algorithm I don't know). If skill equalled water straight up, then there's no reason the significance would always be assigned to one or the other, even though the underlying cause is the water. The same is true when skill is collinear with water. The significance could go either way

Comment: Apparently, whichever turns out to be significant is thought to be primarily (and "independently") related. So, if water is significant and skill is not, all effect of skill is through water. On the other hand, if skill is significant and not water, then skill is more important and bivariate relation between growth and water is only a reflection of skill. That's the way it is generally explained in biomedical studies.

Comment: See another study: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32658813/  It says "multiple regression indicated that age, marriage, education, SAS, PSQI, IES-R total score, Avoidance and Hyperarousal factor were independent predictors of depressive symptom". Any other predictor variables that were entered in regression equation are thought not to be "independent" or primary determinants of response variable (even though there may be multicollinearity).

Comment: Interesting. I was taught there was no way to know which of collinear variables would be assigned significance, but looks like you're right.